# Android ProgressBar not showing and native contacts lookup is slow

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-progressbar, contactscontract

I have 2 issues -
1. The progress bar (spinner) is not showing at all. Its as if it was never there.
2. Is there a better way for me to look-up and load the native contact list into the arraylist? I only need the contact name and phone numbers to be populated (if a contact has more than one phone number, both should appear). For about 300 contacts, it takes 3.5 seconds. Not too slow. But the user should see the progressbar while they wait so that they know that its working.

The following is my main activity -

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {

//declaring references for layout components - buttons, checkboxes, etc
ProgressBar pbLoadingSpinner;

ArrayList<Map<String, String>> nativeContactList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //initializing references to layout components

    pbLoadingSpinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);

    pbLoadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //
    //
    //

    populateContactList();
    pbLoadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}


private void populateContactList(){

    long tStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int contactCount = 0;

    Uri allContactsQueryUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] allContactsProjection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER};
    String allContactsSelection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1";

    CursorLoader allContactsLoader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(), allContactsQueryUri, allContactsProjection, allContactsSelection, null, null);
    Cursor allContacts = (Cursor) allContactsLoader.loadInBackground();

    nativeContactList.clear();

    while(allContacts.moveToNext()){

        String contactName = allContacts.getString(allContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String contactId = allContacts.getString(allContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String hasPhoneNums = allContacts.getString(allContacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

        if(Integer.parseInt(hasPhoneNums)>0){

            Uri perContactUri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
            String[] perContactProjection = new String[] {
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
            String perContactSelection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+" = "+contactId;

            //Cursor allPhoneNums = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+" = "+contactId,null,null);

            CursorLoader perContactCursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(),perContactUri,perContactProjection,perContactSelection,null,null);
            Cursor perContactCursor = (Cursor) perContactCursorLoader.loadInBackground();

            while(perContactCursor.moveToNext()){
                String contactPhoneNumber = perContactCursor.getString(perContactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                Map<String,String> namePhone = new HashMap<String, String>();
                namePhone.put("Name", contactName);
                namePhone.put("Phone",contactPhoneNumber);
                nativeContactList.add(namePhone);
            }
            perContactCursor.close();
            contactCount++;
        }
    }

    Log.v("VERBOSE_PHONE_TAG", "Contact count =" + contactCount);

    allContacts.close();

    double elapsedSeconds = (System.currentTimeMillis() - tStart)/ 1000.0;

    Log.v("VERBOSE_PHONE_TAG", "Elapsed Time =" + elapsedSeconds);
}    
}
```

My xml layout looks like -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragment_simple_call"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `populateContactList();` in `onCreate()`, you are doing the entire database query on the UI thread, blocking the UI from updating (including your ProgressBar spinning).

You should consider using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to run `populateContactList()` on a background thread (by calling it in the AsyncTask's `doInBackground()` method) and then hide the progress bar and update the screen with the results in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I just tried that. In the onPostExecute() I essentially, hide the progress bar and then create a simple adapter (containing the arraylist populate in doInBackground()) and attach the adapter to an autocomplete text-view. Now I get a "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()".

Comment: Sounds like you aren't calling new MyAsyncTask().execute() from the UI thread - in theory you should just call that where you currently have `populateContactList()`.

Comment: I am already doing that :) Upon further investigation, the error is pin-pointed to the line with the CursorLoader leading me to believe that I cannot use a CursorLoader inside an AsyncTask. Is that so?

Comment: Ah, no you don't need a `CursorLoader` at all - `Cursor allContacts = getContentResolver().query(allContactsQueryUri, allContactsProjection, allContactsSelection, null, null)` is enough.